# Access 365 VBA subform's query based table is displaying query design check boxes and can't interact with table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an unbound subform in a form, which when clicking a button on the form populates the unbound subform's Sourceobject with a stored query reference in VBA, to populate the subform with a datasheet view in the subform.

Me.subfrm.SourceObject = "Query.storedquery"

In Access 365 when viewing a table after clicking a button, if you move the mouse cursor about 5 rows down, what I think is the row of query design check boxes appear as the mouse moves across the screen.  Typing or using the arrow keys just makes a grey cell appear, which looks like the query criteria cells.  Not pictured, but sometimes the top phantom cell when clicked, will make a combobox with the subform's query's table reference from design view appear in the cell.

[Result of moving mouse over table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQE1F.png)

The table can't be interacted with as well; no edits, selection, highlighting.

It is as if there is an invisible design window over top of the subform table.

Has anyone encountered this?  Did you find a solution?  Switching the subform to reference a table instead of the simple query fixes the issue, but I need the queries for formatting etc.

I switched the query reference to a table reference and that fixed the issue, but I need to use queries.

Comment: Funky. Please edit your question and add the code that sets the recordsource. Also not sure what you mean by "VBA query reference" - just the name of a stored query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known recent issue.

It is expected to be solved with one of the upcoming updates.

Comment: Thanks! A link: https://www.accessforever.org/post/display-bugs-in-access-365-version-2302

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I resized the subform to 0 in design view, then reset and grew it back to normal for each table viewing button.
Me.subfrm.Height = 0 then Me.subfrm.Height = normalsize